# sp_executesql - What is wrong with my Parameter-string?

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

I've stared myself blind at this. It started as a more complex procedure, but I've stripped it down to the bare bones, trying to make it run. This is the current code:

```sql
DECLARE @sql NVarchar(MAX) = '
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, @num;
END'

EXEC [sp_executesql] @sql, N'@num int', @num = 1;
```

It simply refuses. It's worth mentioning that if I run the code without the parameter-part (`@sql` being the sole parameter to the `sp_executesql` function) it runs fine. I've tried other syntax alternatives, such as

```
EXEC [sp_executesql] @sql, N'@num int', 1;
```

and

```
DECLARE @params NVarchar(1000) = '@num int';
EXEC [sp_executesql] @sql, @params, 1;
```

What is wrong with my parameter-specification?

**Edit 1**: Included error-message

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
```

Comment: What is the `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test` about? Are you actually trying to create a procedure? Please explain what you want the end result to be after running your `sp_executesql`. A new procedure? A resultset containing the result of `SELECT 1, @num;`?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to create a procedure dynamically. It works fine as long as I don't specify parameters, which makes sense as a preventative feature, except I couldn't find any documentation saying this is intended behaviour.

Comment: So are you hoping the end result will be that `@num` is evaluated as 1 and you end up with `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test AS BEGIN SELECT 1, 1; END`?

Comment: That's exactly it

Comment: What are you hoping to solve by creating this procedure dynamically?

Comment: We are frequently in need of performing creating stored procedures which contain a bit of boilerplate code, with the exception of a few variables. I just chose to make a script to ease the creation of these procedures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be expecting that the parameters will end up being treated as string interpolation arguments.

They won't.

One way of achieving something similar to what you want would be simply to parameterise the stored procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
@num int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, @num;
END
```

Then when you execute it you supply the desired value.

If you definitely want the procedure to end up with `@num` replaced with a hardcoded `1` you can use.

```
DECLARE @num int = 1

DECLARE @sql NVarchar(MAX) = '
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 1, @num;
END'

SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@num', @num)

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql -- or just EXEC(@sql)
```

Take care of SQL injection if you go this route.

Also you would need to be careful of parameter/place holder names and order of replacements, so if you had place holders `@num` and `@number` the `@number` one would need to be replaced first.

Comment: I was trying to avoid hard-coding parameters into the sql-string by using a parameterized call to `sp_executesql`. While my use-case may sound questionable, I feel `sp_executesql` is putting down more road-blocks than necessary, especially if it is that easy to trick it! Thanks for the answer, this solves my problem.

Comment: The first two statements are not true when it comes to parameterizing dynamic sql.

Comment: @MichaelKeleher parameters can only be used in prescribed positions. Replacing random locations in the text of a stored procedure definition is not one of them.

Comment: He said that one of the requirements is to avoid hard-coding parameters into the sql string. your proposed solution does just that using a replace function.

Answer (score -1):

You should avoid making the entire call dynamic because of the sql injection vulnerability.

Your procedure needs to accept the parameter you are specifying on your dynamic 
sql call as well

```
    @sql='
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
    @num int
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1, @num;
    END'
    exec sp_executesql @sql
```

The proper way to parameterize your dynamic sql is:

```
    DECLARE @params NVarchar(1000) = '@num int';
    EXEC [sp_executesql] @sql, @params, @num=1;
```

Parameterizing dynamic sql also allows the plan in the procedure cache to be reused and is much more efficient for the server. If you ever come across dynamic sql that is not parameterized and you can't modify because it is in a third party software, you can also use plan guides.

Comment: Did you actually look at what the OP is trying to do? Plan reuse for a `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement is not possible and nor would it be desirable to cache these plans as it would be a waste of space.

Comment: Your edited solution simply doesn't do anything sensible. There is no benefit of passing in `, @params, @num=1;` as they in no way change anything and are unused. You just end up creating exactly the same stored procedure as at the top of my answer with the illusion that there might be something dynamic going on.

Comment: You missed the modification to the dbo.test procedure where a parameter is added. The original procedure attempted to use @num without declaring it.

Comment: No I didn't miss that. Try passing different values like `, @params, @num=7` or simply omitting them at all. You will find that none of it makes any difference to what is created.

Comment: Well actually it still gives the `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.` error anyway. But there is no way that you are ever going to end up with a stored procedure containing the text `SELECT 1, 1;` by simply passing in `@num=1` into `sp_executesql` and not doing string replaces/concatenations or equivalent. This is simply not a supported case for parameterisation. You seem to be expecting that the parameters will end up being treated as string interpolation arguments.

They won't.

Comment: So what is the complete executable code that you believe answers the question? How does the first code block relate to the second? The first code block isn't using parameterisation and has no need to be dynamic SQL at all. It is just the same as `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Test
    @num int
    AS
    BEGIN
        SELECT 1, @num;
    END` But if you try and apply the advice in the second to it it gives an "incorrect syntax" error.